# Aligning Caption with image instead of centering

Tags: subfloats

I have 3 sub-figures under each other in one column where I am trying to get their caption right below them. With my current settings I am getting them centered like below.

[image]

My code is as follows, and all my attempts seem not to succeed.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure*}[h]

\begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{Resources/"image1".png}
\caption{caption1}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{Resources/"image2".png}
\caption{caption2}       
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{Resources/"image2".png}
\caption{caption3}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{My Caption}
\label{fig:myLabel}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages? Plese also clarify: You seem to use a `twocolumn` document and a `figure*` environmen that spans both columns but seem to put the images below each other. Are you sure, you want to use a `figure*` rather than a `figure` in such a situation?

Comment: I updated as the question @leandriis by adding those details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three possible layouts based on some assumptions about the desired layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{Resources/"image1".png}
    \caption{caption1}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{Resources/"image2".png}
    \caption{caption2}       
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{Resources/"image2".png}
    \caption{caption3}
  \end{subfigure}

  \caption{My Caption}
  \label{fig:myLabel}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{figure*}

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Resources/"image1".png}
    \caption{caption1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Resources/"image2".png}
   \caption{caption2}       
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Resources/"image2".png}
    \caption{caption3}
  \end{subfigure}

  \caption{My Caption}
  \label{fig:myLabel}

\end{figure*}

\lipsum \lipsum[1-3]


\begin{figure}[h]
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{Resources/"image1".png}
    \caption{caption1}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{Resources/"image2".png}
    \caption{caption2}       
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{Resources/"image2".png}
    \caption{caption3}
  \end{subfigure}

  \caption{My Caption}
  \label{fig:myLabel}

\end{figure}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: @tony9099: It might be interesting to know which of my suggestion was the solution you were actually looking for.

Comment: I was exactly looking for the example of the first image. 3 figures centered and vertically aligned in the first column of a 2 columned page.